# How to make element disappear while resizing window

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to make elements disappear while decreasing window size.
I have 2 images attached to left and right of the page:

```
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
max-height: 240px;
left: 0;
```

The elements should remain **left: 0, and right: 0;** when possible. But in a certain window position (x), they must slowly disappear proportionally out of the window.

Can somebody help me? Thank a lot and sorry for my imperfect English.

Comment: I think the `@media` statement in css is what you're looking for. Duckduckgo it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: /*size*/) {
    /* Resize code goes here */
}
```

And also don't forget to add this meta tag in your head tag in HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```